# Compiling JavaScript files on Win 10

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning JavaScript, and I'm not planning on using it in a web app, just a desktop app. I want to compile my JS files so that I can run them on windows, but the jsc.exe compiler is in the C:\Windows.old folder and it "can't run on my PC." Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you've updated Windows at some point. You're looking at your old installation.

Comment: Yeah I have I'm just wondering if I can get a Win10 friendly compiler :(

Comment: No idea why you'd need a compiler... Have you tried copying it from the old location to the equivalent new location?

Comment: It's [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6(v=vs.90).aspx) so it needs to be compiled. If you started learning javascript, you're doing it wrong, no one uses JSscript anymore, you should go with regular javascript. Do you really need to use javascript for a desktop app? If yes, [github electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As browser provide javascript engine, which allow us run the javascript.

If we wants to javascript run in our machine without browser, we also need the engine.

You can try [Node](https://nodejs.org) to run javascript in machine environment.

Further more, we can build application software use [electron](https://github.com/atom/electron), surely, use javascript.